# Поэтапная обработка элементов li внутри ul

Tags: animate

Добрый день, делаю эффект проявления элементов страницы при скроле, в итоге нужно применить эффект .animate поэтапно к каждому li внутри ul. если просто делать $("ul>li").animate(bla) то он мгномено производит animate ко всем элементам, а мне нужно по очереди(первый появился потом второй итд). Как можно реализовать? через each не получается.

Comment: $("ul>li")[0]

Comment: а если 10ть элементов, или 100? неужели нет другого метода, нежели использовать индексы.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, товарищи!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

война жиквери го http://jsfiddle.net/fR6sV/1/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/fR6sV/